# Best way to fill a map using java steams

Tags: java, java-stream

We have a map that we are filling in multiple calls from a list passed as a param:

```
  Map<String, Double> priceByID
```

Which style is considered a cleaner code to fill our map? Why?

```
list.stream().map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getId(), e.getPrice())).forEach(priceByID.entrySet()::add);
```

OR

```
 Map<String, Double> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getId(), e -> e.getPrice()));
  priceByID.putAll(map);
```

Comment: Why not simply write `Map<String, Double> priceByID = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getId(), e -> e.getPrice()));`?

Comment: `priceByID` already contains any data? If not then there is no need of  `putAll`

Comment: @Eran because priceByID exists already, and we fill it each time we call the method passing a list of new products.

Comment: @Eklavya yes it already contains data

Comment: @Siri A cleaner code is subjective. I vote this question as opinion based & have to be specific.

Comment: I think this should work `list.forEach(e -> priceByID.put(e.getId(), e.getPrice()))` looks cleaner

Comment: @Eklavya isn't using forEach considered a bad practice as it does a side effect?

Comment: @Siri I consider `Collection.forEach()` better than `Stream.forEach()`. I prefer your second way with `putAll()`, though, and consider it conventional.

Comment: @Siri I don't think so, do you have any insight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.stream().map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getId(), e.getPrice())).forEach(priceByID.entrySet()::add);
```

> You are creating a stream of map entries, and the go over it and insert it. there's no real reason to do it, you creating tones of redundant objects

```
Map<String, Double> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getId(), e -> e.getPrice()));
  priceByID.putAll(map);
```

> again, creating redundant map that will be removed afterwards, and also go over the items twice - once on the stream, and again on the putAll

you can use:

```
list.forEach(e -> priceByID.put(e.getId(), e.getPrice()))
```

or even:

```
for (?? entry : list) {
   priceByID.put(entry.getId(), entry.getPrice()));
}
```

it will do the job just the same.

Comment: isn't using forEach considered a bad practice as it does a side effect?

Comment: @Siri - you can use the 'conventional' for loop if you're worried about the side effect. I'm not sure it's such a bad practice